# C: unsigned char * bytes array copying elements to other unsigned char * array

Tags: c, arrays, unsigned-char

I think that copying elements of array like this:

```
unsigned char *new_bytes_array = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*length/2); 
for(int i=0, j=0; i<length; i++) {
  if(i % 2 == 0) continue; 
  new_bytes_array[j] = old_bytes_array[i]; 
  j++;
```

}

is making copy but value not by reference, but I would like to make sure that this will be deep copy not just shallow copy of references or pointers.

I know that this is maybe easy and ridiculous qustion, but I cannot find similar on stack rather memcpy() all array, but I want to copy only some elements for example every second element, or copy 1-3 elements and skip 4th element, (if i%4 == 0 skip element).

Comment: Your code makes a "deep copy" as is.

Comment: Note that `sizeof (unsigned char)` is always 1, so it's just an annoying way to write `1` (wihch in case of a multiplication is pretty pointless). Consider removing it.

Comment: @unwind actually on different platform, `sizeof(unsigned char)` is not always 1. So I think it's not a good idea to remove it.

Comment: @litao3rd No. You are mistaken, that's simply not true. The return value from `sizeof` is units of `char`, so by definition `sizeof (char)` is 1.

Comment: @unwind yep, sizeof(char) is not always 1 on different architecture. And `sizeof` is executed in compile time, so I think `sizeof(unsigned char)` is better than a magic number `1`.

Comment: @litao3rd C11 draft, section 6.5.3.4 §4: "When `sizeof` is applied to an operand that has type `char`, `unsigned char`, or
`signed char`, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1." And I'm aware it's compile-time, my suggestion was to remove it altogether, not replace by a literal `1`.

Comment: @unwind yep, you're right. I misunderstand you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new_bytes_array[j]` evaluates to an `unsigned char`.

Assuming `old_bytes_array[i]` does as well, then this

```
new_bytes_array[j] = old_bytes_array[i];
```

copies an `unsigned char` and not a pointer, not an `unsigned char*`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the assignment you show assigns a single `unsigned char`, i.e. "a byte" on most typical computers, it doesn't copy pointers but raw data.

Here's a complete function that does what you want, and fixes a few minor problems:

```
void * copy_every_second_byte(const void *src, size_t length)
{
  if(src == NULL || length == 0)
    return NULL;
  unsigned char *out = malloc(length / 2);
  for(size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < length; ++i)
  {
    if(i % 2 == 0) continue;
    out[j++] = ((unsigned char *) src)[i];
  }
  return out;
}
```